# How to add custom default bookmark to Gnome Files?

Tags: linux, gnome, xdg-user-dirs

Is there a way to add a custom directory to the default shortcuts to Files' sidebar? Not as a bookmark, as a default XDG directory?

For instance, I've added `XDG_WORK_DIR="$HOME/Work"` to `.config/user-dirs.dirs` to define a new 'Work' XDG folder, which seems to work as `xdg-user-dir WORK` does output `/home/user/Work`.

However, it still doesn't show the 'Work' shortcut in Files.
I've also noted that the default 'Templates' directory is also not shown, so I'm assuming these shortcuts are defined elsewhere - where? It would also be cool to add a specific folder icon as used by the other default shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without modifying the source code of **[nautilus](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/blob/9f875d68153c8a014924420401dc3371ece3e021/src/gtk/nautilusgtkplacessidebar.c#L571)** and **[glib](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/ec754e5404be345fe4b576b65acccf88c72476d3/glib/gutils.h#L241)**, because the icons and the entries in the palces sidebar are **hard-coded**.